# Проблема с циклом for при резервной копии файлов (модули zipfile, os)

Tags: python, python-3.x, zipfile

Знатоки, помогите, пожалуйста)
Пишу элементарную программу для резервного копирования файлов на python, использую модули zipfile, os.
Не могу дать ума как написать последний блок кода (цикл for) так, чтобы он сразу прогонял оба элемента (каталога) из списка source, добавляя их в архив? Пришлось продублировать блок, указав второй элемент списка. Работает конечно, но если список будет значительно больше, уже не так удобно.

Вот мой код:

```
import os
import zipfile

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['/Users/ozzy/Documents/filestobackup', '/Users/ozzy/Documents/filesback']

# 2. Резервные копии будут храниться в следующем каталоге:
target_dir = '/Users/ozzy/Desktop/BACKUP'

# 3. Имя zip-архива
target = 'Backup.zip'

# 4. Создаем архив
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w')

# 5.1 Помещаем первый каталог в архив
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source[0]):
    for file in files:
        zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))

# 5.2 Помещаем второй каталог в архив
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source[1]):
    for file in files:
        zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))

print('Резервное копирование завершено')
```

Кстати, цикл for у меня вызывает сомнения (хотя и работает), поскольку такой код нашел в интернете. Если есть замечания по этому поводу - буду рад!
Заранее большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
for src in source: 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Так к тому же можно будет помещать неограниченное кол-во путей в `source`

Comment: Спасибо, дружище! Долго голову ломал)